# Data loss when writing bytes to a file

Tags: java, string, file, stream, compression

I'm working on a string compressor for a school assignment,

There's one bug that I can't seem to work out. The compressed data is being written a file using a FileWriter, represented by a byte array. The compression algorithm returns an input stream so the data flows as such:

```
piped input stream
-> input stream reader
-> data stored in char buffer
-> data written to file with file writer.
```

Now, the bug is, that with some very specific strings, the second to last byte in the byte array is written wrong. and it's always the same bit values "11111100".

Every time it's this bit values and always the second to last byte.

Here are some samples from the code:

```
  InputStream compress(InputStream){

  //...
  //...

  PipedInputStream pin = new PipedInputStream();
  PipedOutputStream pout = new PipedOutputStream(pin);
  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(pout);

  oos.writeObject(someobject); 
  oos.flush();

  DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(pout);


  dos.writeFloat(//);
  dos.writeShort(//);
  dos.write(SomeBytes); // ---Here 
  dos.flush();
  dos.close();

 return pin;
}

void write(char[] cbuf, int off, int len){

  //....
  //....

  InputStreamReader s = new InputStreamReader(
            c.compress(new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes())));

  s.read(charbuffer);

  out.write(charbuffer);
 }
```

A string which triggers it is "hello and good evenin" for example.

I have tried to iterate over the byte array and write them one by one, it didn't help.

It's also worth noting that when I tried to write to a file using the output stream in the algorithm itself it worked fine. This design was not my choice btw.

So I'm not really sure what i'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by encoding and decoding the bytes with Base64.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you're saying:

> Now, the bug is, that with some very specific strings, the second to
>   last byte in the byte array is written wrong. and it's always the same
>   bit values "11111100".

You are taking a

```
binary stream  (the compressed data)
-> reading it as chars 
-> then writing it as chars.
```

And your are converting bytes to chars without clearly defining the encoding.

I'd say that the problem is that your `InputStreamReader` is translating some byte sequences in a way that you're not expecting.

Remember that in encodings like [utf-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) two or three bytes may become one single char.

It can't be coincidence that the very byte pattern you pointed out (`11111100`) Is one of the utf-8 escape codes (`1111110x`). Check this wikipedia [table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) at and you'll see that uft-8 is destructive since if a byte starts with: `1111110x` the next must start with `10xxxxxx`.

Meaning that if using utf-8 to convert

```
 bytes1[] -> chars[] -> bytes2[]
```

in some cases bytes2 will be different from bytes1.

I recommend changing your code to remove those readers. Or specify ASCII encoding to see if that prevent the translations.

Comment: after some testing, the encoding (or lack thereof) is definitely the issue here.  I'm trying to find a way to write the chars with ISO-8859-1. No luck thus far.

Comment: Why do you need to write this as characters? It's binary data.